# Comparing hashes and outputing differences

Tags: powershell

So I am using the `compare-object` cmdlet to compare 2 hashes that I have created one prior to testing, one after testing.  The goal is to compare the 2 files for hash differences and generate a equal or not equal result on the screen and saving to a file.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content -Path $title2hashstorage/$sha256) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content -Path $source) > hashcompare.txt
```

This works fine and dandy apart from the differences I see with the dates when the 2 hashes were created.

```
InputObject                           SideIndicator
-----------                           -------------
Hash Generated at 10/01/2019 11:07:25 =>           
Hash Generated at 10/01/2019 13:21:03 <=
```

So is there a way just to test the hashes and not the date and return an equal or not equal result?

Comment: Can you provide example file contents you are reading? It ***sounds*** like you want to compare substrings of each line of the two files.

Comment: the `Compare-Object` cmdlet has a `-Property` parameter. use that to compare ONLY the desired property. [*grin*]

Comment: Yeah I keep trying that I and seem to keep screwing up the syntax.  Noob i am

Comment: Such as piping it.

Comment: Something like this??  Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content -Path $title2hashstorage/$sha256) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content -Path $source) -Property (hash) > hashcompare.txt

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way just to test the hashes and not the date and return
>   an equal or not equal result?

Yea, Powershell added some nifty cmdlets to help with that a few releases back. The following sort of what you're after?

```
$first = $(Get-FileHash -Path '.\app.js').Hash
$second = $(Get-FileHash -Path '.\hive.js').Hash
if ($first -eq $second) { Write-Output "Match" } else { Write-Output "Different" }
```

**Updated Answer Based on Comments from Requester**

Unless the file or hash algorithm selected is changed, the hash will the same each time its calculated:

[image]

`Compare-Object` is a mechanism to compare two objects, which are composed of multiple properties. You wouldn't usually use `Compare-Object` in a case like this since you can just compare the two hash strings. Can you modify the sample I've given you to use `Compare-Object`, sure, but it's overkill.

Comment: I have tried that and it comes back different every time.

Comment: $comparison = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content -Path $title2hashstorage/$sha256) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content -Path $source) > hashcompare.txt                 
    
    
        if($comparison.SideIndicator -eq "=>"){
        Write-Host "Discrepancy found in hash!!" -ForegroundColor Red}
        else {
        Write-Host "No discrepancy found."
        }

Comment: @user7716257 I'm not 100% following. What do you mean "...it comes back different everytime"? If you're running `Get-FileHash` on a file and it's coming back different each time, either the file is changing between invocations or something really strange is happening. Can you post your code and results?